# WPF ComboBox mouse selection event is not getting fired

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

which resides within a grid row.

The problem is I am not getting Mouse selection on a any comboboxitem is not getting fired. But from key board, keydown event is getting fired and works perfectly well.

So any idea, why the below XAML ComboBox is not firing mousedown or selectionItem events.

```
<ComboBox Name="StatusCombo"  VerticalAlignment="Center"  MouseDown="StatusCombo_MouseDown"
                      Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="Auto" MinWidth="75" 
                      FontFamily="Arial" FontSize ="10px" FontWeight ="Normal"
                      SelectedIndex="{Binding IndexForSelectedStatus}" 
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemStatus, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=StatusComboCollection,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                      Style="{StaticResource UIRefreshButtonComboBoxStyle}"
                      AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding ElementName=labelStatus,Path=Content}">

                </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Are you following classic pattern/MVVM?

Comment: Try preview mouse down https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/61807025-d4c4-41e0-b648-b11183065009/mousedown-event-not-working-wpf?forum=wpf

Comment: Maybe GridRow is hendling the mouse down event try PreviewMOuseDown how @CaseyPrice is sayd

Answer (score 0):

If you are following MVVM there is an easy way for doing the same:

```
<ComboBox Name="StatusCombo" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=StatusComboCollection,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}>
```

in ViewModel

```
private string _mySelectedItem;
public string MySelectedItem
{
  get { return _mySelectedItem; }
  set {
       //Do the operations here no need for an extra method
       _mySelectedItem = value; 
      }
}
```

**Note:** Since you have implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged interface the property changed event will triggers whenever the selected item changed(independent of triggering source)